# Split string in 64kb using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I would like to split an extremely large string, up to 8mb, in 64kb chunks. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
//1
var regData:String= "string up to 8mb"
var count=((countElements(self.regData!))/65536)

//2
for var index = 0; index < count; ++index {
    arr.append(self.regData!.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(self.regData!.startIndex, 0),end: advance(self.regData!.startIndex, 65536))))
    self.regData!.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: self.regData!.startIndex, end:advance(self.regData!.startIndex, 65536)))
    println(index)
 }
//3
println("exit loop")
arr.append(self.regData!)
```

1. I calculate how many 64 kb chunks I have.
2. In the for loop I get the first 64kb. I collect them in an array. Now I have to delete the first 64kb strings because of step 3.
3. If I I have less than 64kb I get an error in my loop. Therefore my last step is outside the loop.

The code works fine, but it is extremely slow. I need to speed up my code. Do you have any idea how to do it.

Thanks at all.

Comment: what is your reason to not use `NSStream`  ?

Comment: I am new in ios programming :D... I have to look at NSStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more effective if you don't modify the original string,
and just use two indices (`from` and `to`) to traverse through the string:

```
let regData = "string up to 8mb"
let chunkSize = 65536

var array = [String]()
var from = regData.startIndex // start of current chunk
let end = regData.endIndex    // end of string
while from != end {
    // advance "from" by "chunkSize", but not beyond "end":
    let to = from.advancedBy(chunkSize, limit: end)
    array.append(regData.substringWithRange(from ..< to))
    from = to
}
```

Note that this gives substrings of 65536 *characters*. Since a Swift
character represents a "Unicode grapheme cluster", this will not
correspond to 64kB of data. If you need that then you should convert
the string to `NSData` and split that into chunks.

*(Updated for Swift 2.)*

Comment: I will try this and give a feedback :D. Thanks

Comment: Thanks this is very fast :D... Can you give me an example how to handle with NSStream?