# Splitting a string of letters into 3s in swift

Tags: python, arrays, swift, split

Swift newbie here.  I am trying to convert some of my python code to swift and im stuck at the point where I need to split a string of letters into and array with each item being 3 letters:

For example my python code is as follows:

```py
name = "ATAGASSTSSGASTA"
threes =[]
for start in range(0, len(name),3):
   threes.append(name[start : start + 3])
print threes
```

For swift ive come as far as this:

```swift
var name = "ATAGASSTSSGASTA"
let namearr = Array(name)
let threes = []
threes.append(namearr[0...3])
```

This gives me an error.

I realize there may be an much easier way to do this, but I have not been able to find anything in my research. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28560013/1187415. Here is a more generic approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26691258/1187415.

Comment: `split=lambda s,n:[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(s),n)]` ... `threes=split('ATAGASSTSSGASTA',3)`

Answer (score 3):

An easy and Swifty way to do this is to map an array of chars using the `stride` and `advance` functions:

```swift
let name = Array("ATAGASSTSSGASTA")

let splitName = map(stride(from: 0, to: name.count, by: 3)) {
    String(name[$0..<advance($0, 3, name.count)])
}
```

Comment: It may or may not be relevant, but this gives an array of `Slice<Character>`, not an array of `String`. (That's why I used substringWithRange in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28560013/1187415)

Comment: If OP is interested in a String array, you can generate a string from each `Slice<Character>` during the mapping. `String(name[$0..<advance($0, 3, name.count)])`.

Comment: For my case this was very relevant. I am going to us substringWithRange as i need the array of strings. Thank you to all of your answers! much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty verbose, but it does the job:

```
let name = "ATAGASSTSSGASTA"

let array = reduce(name, [String]()) {
    switch $0.last {
    case .Some(let last) where countElements(last) < 3:
        var array = $0
        array[array.endIndex-1].append($1)
        return array
    case .Some(_), .None:
        return $0 + [String($1)]
    }
}
```

Edit: In Swift 1.2, I think `countElements` has changed to just `count`. Not sure, don't have it yet, but the documents make it look that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nucString = "aatttatatatattgctgatctgatctEOS"
let nucArrayChar = Array(nucString)
var nucArray: [String] = []
var counter: Int = nucArrayChar.count

if counter % 3 == 0 {
    for var startNo = 0; startNo < counter; startNo += 3 {
    println("\(nucArray)\(startNo)")
    nucArray.append(String(nucArrayChar[(startNo)...(startNo + 2)]))
    }
}
```