# How to check for palindrome in Swift using recursive definition

Tags: swift, recursion, palindrome

I like many of the features in Swift, but using manipulating strings are still a big pain in the ass.

```
func checkPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool {
    print(word)
    if word == "" {
        return true
    } else {
        if word.characters.first == word.characters.last {
            return checkPalindrome(word.substringWithRange(word.startIndex.successor() ..< word.endIndex.predecessor()))
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This code fails miserably whenever the string's length is an odd number. Of course I could make it so the first line of the block would be `if word.characters.count < 2`, but is there a way in Swift to get substrings and check easily?

**Update**
I like many of the suggestions, but I guess the original question could be misleading a little, since it's a question about String more than getting the right results for the function.

For instance, in Python, checkPalindrome(word[1:-1]) would work fine for the recursive definition, whereas Swift code is much less graceful since it needs other bells and whistles.

Comment: you can check String(characters.reverse()) == self

Comment: check if word.characters.count % 2 == 1 and delete the character at the center if true

Comment: Manipulating strings in Swift is NOT a "pain in the ass"!

Comment: It "fails miserably" for length==1 because Swift does not allow to create a range with startIndex>endIndex.

Comment: Actually what I learned the other day is that you can easily convert a string into an array like this. `var stringArray = Array(string)`. that will easily convert any string into an array. This is using swift of course but you get my drift. Then to change around the string just use `stringArray[0] = stringArray[1]` that will interchange both of those letters. and wallah you now have the characters switched

Answer (score 19):

```
return word == String(word.reversed())
```

Answer (score 6):

```
func isPalindrome(myString:String) -> Bool {
    let reverseString = String(myString.characters.reversed())
    if(myString != "" && myString == reverseString) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

print(isPalindrome("madam"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not relevant anymore since `String.characters` was deprecated in Swift 3.2.

Comment: @RostyslavDruzhchenko, you could just replace `String(myString.characters.reversed())`  with `myString.reversed()` and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

I have used the below extension to find whether the number is Palindrome or Not.

```
extension String {
    var isPalindrome: Bool {
        return self == String(self.reversed())
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes having a front end for a recursion can simplify life.  I sometimes do this when the arguments which are most convenient to use are not what I want in the user interface.

Would the following meet your needs?

```
func checkPalindrome(str: String) -> Bool {
  func recursiveTest(var charSet: String.CharacterView) -> Bool {
    if charSet.count < 2 {
      return true
    } else {
      if charSet.popFirst() != charSet.popLast() {
        return false
      } else {
        return recursiveTest(charSet)
      }
    }
  }
  return recursiveTest(str.characters)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string into an Array. When the loop is executed get the first index and compare with the last index.

```
func palindrome(string: String)-> Bool{
    let char = Array(string)
    for i in 0..<char.count / 2 {
        if char[i] != char[char.count - 1 - i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var letters: Self { filter(\.isLetter) }
    var isPalindrome: Bool {
        let letters = self.letters
        return String(letters.reversed()).caseInsensitiveCompare(letters) == .orderedSame
    }
}
```

---

```
"Dammit I'm Mad".isPalindrome    // true
"Socorram-me subi no onibus em marrocos".isPalindrome   // true
```

---

You can also break your string into an array of characters and iterate through them until its half comparing one by one with its counterpart:

---

```
func checkPalindrome(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    let chars = Array(word.letters.lowercased())
    for index in 0..<chars.count/2 {
        if chars[index] != chars[chars.count - 1 - index] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

---

And the recursive version fixing the range issue where can't form a range with endIndex < startIndex:

---

```
func checkPalindrome<T: StringProtocol>(_ word: T) -> Bool {
    let word = word.lowercased()
        .components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters).joined()
        .components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).joined()
    if word == "" || word.count == 1 {
        return true
    } else {
        if word.first == word.last {
            let start = word.index(word.startIndex,offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: word.endIndex) ?? word.startIndex
            let end = word.index(word.endIndex,offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: word.startIndex) ?? word.endIndex
            return checkPalindrome(word[start..<end])
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
checkPalindrome("Dammit I'm Mad")
```

Comment: Great answer, but OP seems to want a recursive solution, perhaps ad an exercise.

Comment: The question is more about how to get substrings than how to check if string is palindrome

Comment: @WoominJoshPark "but is there a way in Swift to get substrings and check easily?" also you should take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/34281720/2303865

Answer (score 2):

just add on more condition in if

```
        func checkPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool {
        print(word)
    if (word == "" || word.characters.count == 1){
            return true

        }
    else {
            if word.characters.first == word.characters.last {
                return checkPalindrome(word.substringWithRange(word.startIndex.successor() ..< word.endIndex.predecessor()))
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you make an extension to String like this one then it will make your life easier:

```
extension String {
    var length: Int { return characters.count }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[startIndex.advancedBy(index)]
    }

    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> String {
        return self[Range<Index>(start: startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex), end: startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex))]
    }
}
```

With it in place, you can change your function to this:

```
func checkPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool {
    if word.length < 2 {
        return true
    } 

    if word.characters.first != word.characters.last {
        return false
    }

    return checkPalindrome(word[1..<word.length - 1])
}
```

Quick test:

```
print(checkPalindrome("aba")) // Prints "true"
print(checkPalindrome("abc")) // Prints "false"
```

Comment: Good answer, but we're still checking for word length. It doesn't work as gracefully as word[1:-1] in Python...

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {

    func trimmingFirstAndLastCharacters() -> String {
        guard let startIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: self.endIndex) else {
            return self
        }

        guard let endIndex = index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: self.startIndex) else {
            return self
        }

        guard endIndex >= startIndex else {
            return self
        }

        return String(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
    }

    var isPalindrome: Bool {
        guard count > 1 else {
            return true
        }

        return first == last && trimmingFirstAndLastCharacters().isPalindrome
    }
}
```

We first declare a function that removes first and last characters from a string.

Next we declare a computer property which will contain the actual recursive code that checks if a string is palindrome.

If string's size is less than or equal 1 we immediately return `true` (strings composed by one character like `"a"` or the empty string `""` are considered palindrome), otherwise we check if first and last characters of the string are the same and we recursively call `isPalindrome` on the current string deprived of the first and last characters.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not recursive, but it is a O(n) pure index based solution without filtering anything and without creating new objects. Non-letter characters are ignored as well.

It uses two indexes and walks outside in from both sides.

I admit that the extension type and property name is stolen from Leo, I apologize.

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var isPalindrome : Bool {
        if isEmpty { return false }
        if index(after: startIndex) == endIndex { return true }
        var forward = startIndex
        var backward = endIndex
        while forward < backward {
            repeat { formIndex(before: &backward) } while !self[backward].isLetter
            if self[forward].lowercased() != self[backward].lowercased() { return false }
            repeat { formIndex(after: &forward) } while !self[forward].isLetter
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution in Swift:

```
func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool {
    
    // If no string found, return false
    if word.count == 0 { return false }
    
    var index = 0
    var characters = Array(word) // make array of characters
    while index < characters.count / 2 { // repeat loop only for half length of given string
        if characters[index] != characters[(characters.count - 1) - index] {
            return false
        }
        index += 1
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't really thinking of this, but I think I came up with a pretty cool extension, and thought I'd share.

```
extension String {
    var subString: (Int?) -> (Int?) -> String {
        return { (start) in
            { (end) in
                let startIndex = start ?? 0 < 0 ? self.endIndex.advancedBy(start!) : self.startIndex.advancedBy(start ?? 0)
                let endIndex = end ?? self.characters.count < 0 ? self.endIndex.advancedBy(end!) : self.startIndex.advancedBy(end ?? self.characters.count)

                return startIndex > endIndex ? "" : self.substringWithRange(startIndex ..< endIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}


let test = ["Eye", "Pop", "Noon", "Level", "Radar", "Kayak", "Rotator", "Redivider", "Detartrated", "Tattarrattat", "Aibohphobia", "Eve", "Bob", "Otto", "Anna", "Hannah", "Evil olive", "Mirror rim", "Stack cats", "Doom mood", "Rise to vote sir", "Step on no pets", "Never odd or even", "A nut for a jar of tuna", "No lemon, no melon", "Some men interpret nine memos", "Gateman sees name, garageman sees nametag"]

func checkPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool {
    if word.isEmpty { return true }
    else {
        if word.subString(nil)(1) == word.subString(-1)(nil) {
            return checkPalindrome(word.subString(1)(-1))
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

for item in test.map({ $0.lowercaseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") }) {
    if !checkPalindrome(item) {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func checkPalindrome(_ inputString: String) -> Bool {
    if inputString.count % 2 == 0 {
        return false
    } else if inputString.count == 1 {
        return true
    } else {
        var stringCount = inputString.count
        while stringCount != 1 {
            if inputString.first == inputString.last {
                stringCount -= 2
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }
        if stringCount == 1 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let inputString0 = "aabaa"
checkPalindrome(inputString0)

let inputString1 = "abcuabc"
checkPalindrome(inputString1)

let inputString2 = "abac"
checkPalindrome(inputString2)

Comment: Please try including an explanation with your code, as it makes for a better answer.

Comment: Your function returns `false` for the string "abba" (which is a palindrome), it returns `true` for the string "abcda" (which is not a palindrome), and it never terminates for the string "abcde". – Also the question was about recursion and substrings, and code-only answers without any explanation are useless for future readers.