# Unable to convert hex string to uint8 byte array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hex, uint8array

i need to convert hex string to byte array using swift. I have tried with following example hex string

`"7B737369643A32333A34333A34353A31352C70617373776F72643A31323334357D"`

This is my code

```
func sendCmd (CMD: [UInt8],length: Int ,hexString: String)
    {

        var tosend = Array<UInt8>()
        var lenval = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 2)
        lenval[0] = (UInt8)(length & 0xff)
        lenval[1] = (UInt8)((length >> 8) & 0xff)

        tosend.append(CMD[0])
        tosend.append(CMD[1])
        tosend.append(lenval[0])
        tosend.append(lenval[1])
}
```

I got output like this

```
[123, 115, 115, 105, 100, 58, 50, 51, 58, 52, 51, 58, 52, 53, 58, 49, 53, 44, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 58, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 125]
```

But i need to get output like this

```
 [0x7B, 0x73, 0x73, 0x69, ......]
```

and finally i have to append output array to "tosend" byte array(Array).

Any idea?

Comment: Your code is correct. There is no difference between 0x7B and 123. To convert your byte array to data just initialize it using the Data initializer  `Data(tosend)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546967/hex-string-convert-string-uint8-array-convert-string-swift-swift-2/33548238#33548238

Comment: But i need to write tosend data to BLE(bluetooth device), since it accept hex format, array item  should be in hex format. Am i correct?

Comment: What do you mean hex format?  Do you need an array of strings?

Comment: This is what am expecting,  let bytes : [UInt8] = [0xA5, 0x00, 0x16]

Comment: Like I said your code is correct.

Comment: tosend is an array of UInt8 what's wrong with it?

Comment: So there is no need to convert [123, 115, 115, 105, 100, 58..]  to  [0x7B, 0x73, 0x73, 0x69, ......] , But is the byte array  ok with BLE write

Comment: The way you write the number (byte) decimal 123, hexa 0x7b or binary 0b01111011 in Xcode makes no difference. What matters it is your object type

Comment: @shamly: Try `print(123, 0x7B)` or `print(123 == 0x7B)` to convince yourself. As Leo said, 123 and 0x7B are representations of the *same number* in different number bases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift . This is acceptable answer.