# How to convert Hexadecimal for Bluetooth LE write characteristic Swift 4

Tags: swift, bluetooth, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

What function do I need to pass 0x04 as a Data value to Peripheral characteristic in BLE? What int value can I pass to get a byte 0x04?

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if let characteristics = service.characteristics {

        // I WANT TO WRITE 0x04 TO THE PERIPHERAL USING enableBytes below
        // enableByte MUST BE A SINGLE BYTE

        var enableValue:UInt8 = 4
        let enableByte = Data(bytes: &enableValue, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        // This returns 04
        // print("enableByte is \(enableByte as NSData)")

        // writing to Characteristics
        for characteristic in characteristics {

            if characteristic.uuid == Device.OnOffUUID {
                self.peripheral?.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

                self.peripheral?.writeValue(enableByte, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)

                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic) // this will call peripheral(_: didUpdateValueFor characteristic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work. I don't like `Data` "Swift version of `NSData` because its `description` method isn't helpful. If you do `let enableByteNSData = enableByte as NSData; print("enableByteNSData: \(enableByteNSData)")` you'll see you have sent `04`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548238/2303865

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155955/discussion-between-richc-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @LeoDabus - do you know a function that converts back from <04> to UInt8?

Comment: just get your `data.first` it will return the first byte out of you data (collection of bytes UInt8)

Comment: @LeoDabus and how to convert byte to an Int?

Comment: byte is a UInt8 `Int(yourbyte)`

Comment: Let int = Int(data.first) gives error cannot invoke initialiser for type Int with type data.element

Comment: You just need to unwrap your optional byte `let data = Data([4])
if let byte = data.first {
    let int = Int(byte)
}`. first returns an optional because your collection my be empty