# Where do I get the 128-character hex-encoded encryption key to open an encrypted Realm with Realm Studio?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, realm

Our Swift app uses Realm (10.7.6) and it's encrypted. I'd like to open the .realm file in Realm Studio (10.1.2) but it's asking for the "128-character hex-encoded encryption key". I'm not sure where to get this.

Btw, in my test app I can open that .realm file with Realm Studio if I don't encrypt so the versions of RealmSwift and Realm Studio are compatible.

To encrypt the Realm in the app I'm using the `getKey()` code from the Realm docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/encrypt-a-realm/). The key that gets generated in that code is only 64 bytes, not 128 which is what Realm Studio is asking for. If I `print(key)` I get "64 bytes" in the console. If I add a breakpoint and `po key` it's not much better:

```
▿ 64 bytes
  - count : 64
  ▿ pointer : 0x0000600003a14160
    - pointerValue : 105553177166176
```

Where do I get the "128-character hex-encoded encryption key" that Realm Studio is asking for?

---

Update: As mentioned in Jay's answer below, I used Johannes Lund's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string) to convert the `Data` object to a hex string. Sure enough, I could take that string and paste it into that Realm Studio window.

Sadly, as documented on the Realm site, you can't have an encrypted Realm open in multiple processes. I've been using Realm Studio to help test our collection observers but now we'll have to do that another way.

Comment: you need to use the same used to encrypt

Comment: @LeoDabus that's what I thought but how? As I describe above, when I po the value of the key to the console or print it, I don't get anything I can copy and paste into Realm Studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548238/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption key is an NSData (Data) object. You can make an NSString object of the key that represents that data as hexadecimal values. You can then use that string with Realm Studio

I generally post code based answers but there are already a lot of examples here on SO for mapping Data to a Hex String. Check out the Swift 5 answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/converting-hex-string-to-nsdata-in-swift). There are a lot of other [options for Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DData%20to%20Hex%20String%20Swift%204) and above as well. And [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string)

Comment: Thanks. I used the answer from Johannes Lund from your last link. Worked great!